# Access 2013 sql query help in displaying multiple columns and most recent log of the unique id on the top of the form

Tags: microsoft-metro

I  have a log table with mutiple columns such as name, Dob, contact type, loan number, entry date, etc. Each loan number can have multiple row of logs because of diff contact type and entry dates. There could be entry dates from same date as well.

Now my questin is, how do I write a sql statement that will show all the columns from the table but the most recent log of that loan number shows up on the top of the form I created from the above table that is displayed as datasheet view not s single view?

The reason for this is that the most recent log of the same loan no should be displayed first.

Comment: What you tried so for?

Answer (score 0):

In the design view of the query, I put Max under the total instead of group by. This is giving me an error.

I need to display the most recent log on the top of the datasheet view in the form.